# is it true that XHTML is not supported by IE but many people still use it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml

so i heard that XHTML is not supported by IE and so it is treated as HTML 4.01 any way, but still many people still use it... is that true?

one example is that

<div id="contentForAjax" />

in XHTML, it is self closing, but IE will treat it as not closing, and mess up later layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serving XHTML with the recommended content type `application/xhtml+xml` is not supported.

See [XHTML - myths and reality](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/xhtml.html#types) for more information on this.

Comment: do you mean XHTML with other content type is supported by IE?

Comment: You can use the Content Type text/html, but if you do your document will be treated as HTML, not as XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, IE does not properly support XHTML. A lot of XHTML is actually served as HTML anyway (i.e., it has a text/html MIME type and is parsed as HTML).

WebKit's Maciej posted a good [rundown of XHTML support and how it's commonly parsed](http://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/) on the Surfin' Safari blog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

And Googlebot does the same thing.